# Insert into database if record doesn't exist?

Tags: mysql, insert

I have looked for a way to try this, and so far the bet answer is using the `INSERT IGNORE` syntax, but my problem is that I won't be working with the id's.

Is there a way to insert a record into the database only if it doesn't exist, if you don't know the record id?

eg: I want to check if the data in `col1` ('Hello') doesn't already exist.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (col1, col2) values ('Hello', 1);
```

Existing record:

```
+--------------------+
| table_name         |
+--------------------+
| id  | col1  | col2 |
+--------------------+
| 2   | Hello | 1    |
|     |       |      |
```

Comment: you will `INSERT` against what `id`??..your current query will update all rows!!

Comment: @NoobEditor I know. I'm asking how can I do this *without* that happening?

Comment: @Be0wulf yes that question was what I was looking for. Voted this as dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe [ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) suits your situation

Example query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (id, col1, col2) VALUES (1,'Hello', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = col1,col2 = col2;
```

**Update:** I have added `id` column value in query. This query check if `id=1` already exists then it will not insert, if not exists it will insert

### Update

---

If you want to check duplicate for `col1` column you have to add `unique constrain` on this column

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD UNIQUE (col1)
```

SO now query of inserting and checking duplicate is:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (col1, col2) VALUES ('Hello', 1)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1 = col1,col2 = col2;
```

> If you specify **ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**, and a row is inserted that
>   would cause a duplicate value in a **UNIQUE index** or **PRIMARY KEY**

Comment: This just added a new row. I think it's because there is no reference to the `id` (primary key)?

Comment: You don't have to give reference `id` column its automatically check duplicate in a unique index or primary key

Comment: Well, like I said before, it just added a new row, with the exact same data...

Comment: for this example use `col1` to check for duplicate data. I'll update the question.

Comment: @Ben don't forgot to delete your unwanted comments after i read them

Comment: The update did it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. MYSQL works on id only. If you want it to work on col1 then you can write something like this

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name (col1, col2) 
values ('Hello', 1) WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT col1 from table_name 
                                       WHERE col1 = 'Hello')
```

But again add some more description to answer it properly.

Comment: What is _"Name"_ here? Is this column name??

Comment: OOPS "Name" is column name :)

Comment: I get a syntax error "unexpected where, end of query or ';' expected"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ON DUPLICATE` to insert a record, if existed, it will update. And if not exist, it will insert 
eg:

```
  Insert into table_name (col1, col2) values ('Hello', 1);
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col1=values(col1),col2=values(col2)
```